# How to submit a form with AJAX/JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, submit

Currently my AJAX is working like this:

**index.php**

```
<a href='one.php' class='ajax'>One</a>    
<div id="workspace">workspace</div>
```

**one.php**

```
$arr = array ( "workspace" => "One" );
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajax').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.getJSON(this.href, function(snippets) {
            for(var id in snippets) {
                jQuery('#' + id).html(snippets[id]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above code is working perfectly. When I click link **'One'** then **one.php** is executed and String **"One"** is loaded into **workspace DIV**.

## Question:

Now I want to submit a form with AJAX. For example I have a form in **index.php** like this.

```
<form id='myForm' action='one.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' name='myText'>
 <input type='submit' name='myButton' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

When I submit the form then **one.php** should print the textbox value in workspace DIV.

```
$arr = array ( "workspace" => $_POST['myText'] );
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

How to code js to submit the form with AJAX/JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Submitting the form is easy:

```
$j('#myForm').submit();
```

However that will post back the entire page.

A post via an Ajax call is easy too:

```
$j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'one.php',
    data: { 
        myText: $j('#myText').val(), 
        myButton: $j('#myButton').val()
    },
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
        $j('div.ajax').html(response);
    }
});
```

If you then want to do something with the result you have two options - you can either explicitly set the `success` function (which I've done above) or you can use the `load` helper method:

```
$j('div.ajax').load('one.php', data);
```

Unfortunately there's one messy bit that you're stuck with: populating that `data` object with the form variables to post.

However it should be a fairly simple loop.

Comment: I also answered the complete solution here. If you will edit your answer then  SO will allow me to vote you.

Answer (score 8):

**Here is my complete solution:**

```
jQuery('#myForm').live('submit',function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'one.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            for(var id in data) {
                jQuery('#' + id).html(data[id]);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `$.ajaxSubmit` function in the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Should be as simple as

```
 $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit();
```

You may also want to bind to the form submit event so that all submissions go via AJAX, as the example on the linked page shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form with jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method like this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'one.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
 success:function(data){
   alert(data);
 }
});
```