# What is the purpose of data option in jQuery.ajax() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
type:"post",
data:"name="+name+"&article="+article",
```

what is the two name mean in the part of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not
>   already a string. It's appended to the
>   url for GET-requests. See processData
>   option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value
>   pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting

**For example:** You are posting name and location to a PHP script to store in database like this.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Now In **some.php** file you can access POST values like this:

```
$_POST['name']; // John
$_POST['location']; // Boston
```

Comment: @NAVEED, so the first name is field in the database ? the second name is the id of the button?

Comment: @cj333: No No. There is not any database field. I supposed that if you want to send two values(`name` and `location`) to a php script(`some.php`) to save in database then how you can do this using jQuery. Here in above jQuery code, `name` and `location` are same as you post a form with two fields(`name` and `location`) with `some.php` action in form.

Comment: @NAVEED, in your example, if the html part is `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><input type="text" name="location" id="location" />` so the ajax part is `data: "name" + name +"&location="+location` ?

Comment: @cj333: Yes you are near to point.. Calling above jQuery code in my answer is same as you submit following form: `<form method="POST" action="some.php"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><input type="text" name="location" id="location" /></form>`

Comment: @cj333: You are welcome. I also learned jQuery from this site. Here are my some related questions which may help you. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438123/how-to-submit-a-form-with-ajax-json 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506272/php-problem-submitting-form-in-ajax-json

Answer (score 1):

its the data that you are sending to the server for processing.
so in your example you are sending the server:

```
field "name"
value "whatever is in the name variable"
```

so now the server can look up the the name field, use its value to do whatever it is you are asking the server to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: {
       name: "John",
       location: "Boston"
   },
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
});
```

if it is not helpful please check the fallowing [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: It may be working code, but it's not an answer to the question about the parameters.